# Pine Script How To IF-THEN-AND

Tags: if-statement, pine-script

I have a statement (if x then do y). How can I add a second action (if x then do y AND z)?

```
count = 0
if (x)
    do y AND count += 1
```

Also, would you specify the type for count, and what is pine script's equivalent of =+?
Is there a place to play around with code, like a sandbox/console (similar to JavaScript).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All actions in the [if](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-docs/en/v5/language/Conditional_structures.html) block will get excuted:

```
count = 0
if (x)
    do y 
    count += 1
```

> Also, would you specify the type for count

You don't have to, unless it's `na`. All of the following is correct:

```
int count = 0
count = 0

int count = na
count = int(na)
```

> what is pine script's equivalent of =+

+= in pine script is the same as in other languages.

> Is there a place to play around with code, like a sandbox/console (similar to JavaScript)

There is no console in pine script. Read [this](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-docs/en/v5/writing/Debugging.html) to get help with debuging.

Answer (score 0):

```
count=0 
for i= 0 to countyouwant 
 if a=b do y 
  count:=count+1 
 else if do somethingelse 
  count:=count +1 `
```

No end if or next needed for close the loop.
Just be carefull about vertical line blocks.
Because vertical lines represents end if or next in the queries.